# NSDateFormatter: Only show localized dates if app is localized for the language

Tags: ios, cocoa, localization, nsdateformatter, nslocale

I'm currently writing an app for the iPhone that heavily works with dates. I'm using `NSDateFormatter` to convert dates to strings. Conveniently, `NSDateFormatter` automatically creates strings in the user's language based on the region format.
Because I can't localize my app in all possible languages and regions, the app is only localized in English, German, Spanish and a few others.

When the app is running for a French user for example, the app defaults to English. That is fine, but the dates will still be converted using the French language. This results in strings like "Month: Juillet" instead of "Month: July".

How can I make the `NSDateFormatter` always use the language the app runs in?
I know that I could use `NSLocalizedString()` to localize `NSLocale` identifiers, but this will yield in incorrect region settings.

When the user usually uses a "en_GB" region and my app is localized for English in general, I want the `NSDateFormatter` to use "en_GB" and not just "en" or "en_US". When the user runs French, I want the locale to be "en" and if he runs the app in the "de_DE" region, I want the date formats to be "de_DE", too, because the app supports German.

Regards,
Fabian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create the date formatter, it initialises it's style from the current locale, but you can override this.

[not tested]
You can get the best locale from the users list and your available locale using
NSBundle:

```
+ (NSArray *)preferredLocalizationsFromArray:(NSArray *)localizationsArray
```

NSFormatter:

```
+ (NSString *)dateFormatFromTemplate:(NSString *)template options:(NSUInteger)opts locale:(NSLocale *)locale
```

Should give you a localised format string for the specified locale.

You can then use setDateFormat to override the initial date format for the formatter.

Comment: You're right. Using `-[NSBundle preferredLocalizations]` (which uses `+preferredLocalizationsFromArray:` internally) I got it working correctly. Thank you!

Comment: `dateFormatFromTemplate:` is only necessary if the built-in date and time styles don't meet your needs. Otherwise, you should prefer them over a date format string.

Comment: Yes, I use that only for formats like `MMMM YYYY` and the `dateStyle` and `timeStyle` properties for everything else.